# Docker build causes vagrant image to lose connection

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have a vagrant image in which i'm performing some docker builds on an npm module.
Almost every few builds my vagrant image dies with the error

```
[vagrant@vagrant vagrant]$ docker build --tag="test-builder" .
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

when i ssh into the image and look back in /vagrant it is empty ie my src code is gone again.

The only way I can get the src code back is by doing a

```
vagrant destroy; vagrant up
```

I'm not sure why it dies regularly or why when I ssh back into it my src code is gone

Comment: Hi, Very hard to say with very less info given. Please post atleast (a) Your host OS version (b) vagrant version (c) docker version in vagrant (d) Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my ~/.ssh/config fixed it

```
Host *

ServerAliveInterval 25

serveralivecountmax 20
```